# ¿Cómo puedo corregir el Error al crear una tabla en Mysql?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Esta tabla esta creada en un motor de base de datos MMSQL pero al crear la misma tabla en MySQL

```
CREATE TABLE prueba (

    CDoc   CHAR(20)  NOT NULL,
    Ser   INT       NOT NULL,
    Cor   INT       NOT NULL,
    Sta   CHAR (10) NULL,
    CODIGO  VARCHAR(20) AS (RIGHT('0000'+CAST(SER AS VARCHAR),4)+'-  '+RIGHT('000000000'+CAST(COR AS VARCHAR),10)),
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (SER,COR )
    )
GO
```

me genera el siguiente error

`Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as RIGHT('0000'+CAST(SER AS VARCHAR),4)+'-'+RIGHT('000000000'+CAST(COR AS VARCHA' at line 7   0.016 sec`

¿Por qué me está generando el error de que no admite la columna de este campo al crearse

```
 CODIGO VARCHAR(20) AS RIGHT('0000'+CAST(SER AS VARCHAR),4)+'-'+RIGHT('000000000'+CAST(COR AS VARCHAR),10)
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (SER,COR )
```

Comment: No puedes tomar una sentencia para SQL Server y asumir que te va a funcionar en otra base de datos como MySQL. Cada base de datos tiene su propia sintaxis, de modo que si quieres una sentencia que funciona en MySQL, lee la documentación de MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

La creación de registros con campos calculados depende de que versión de MySQL estés usando: [generated columns](http://mysqlserverteam.com/generated-columns-in-mysql-5-7-5/).

Y la directiva `CLUSTERED` no se admite en MySQL de la misma forma que en MSSQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html

Comment: Buenos días josé justo estaba investigando y el problema es por mi versión de MYSQL el mio es el 5.6.17 y encontrado esa informacion en el siguiente link https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=77837  tambien estoy utilizando el MYSQL workbench voy a seguir investigando muchas gracias  José

Comment: @Libra2880 aparte de que la versión es un problema, la sentencia SQL contiene algunos errores. Por ejemplo: falta el tipo de dato para CODIGO, y falta una coma separando la columna CODIGO y la definición de la clave